# Python Pandas dataframe: For each month of the year, add the date with last day in the month to an index if month not present, or remove duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, multi-index

First of all my apologies for the somewhat convoluted title.

I struggled to find a way to succinctly describe what I have been struggling to achieve for a few hours. Allow me to explain the problem more clearly (FYI I'm using `Python 3.6` and `Pandas 20.3`).

I have a `MultiIndex DataFrame` that currently looks like this:

```
                            d   p
name            paymentDate

Rib Smoth       2011-01-01  0   0
                2011-02-01  0   0
                2011-03-01  0   0
                2011-04-01  0   0
                2011-05-01  0   0
                2011-06-01  0   0
                2011-07-01  0   0
                2011-08-01  0   0
                2011-09-01  0   0
                2011-10-01  0   0
                2011-11-01  0   0
                2011-12-01  0   0
Balrud Big      2011-01-02  1   1
                2011-01-12  2   1
                2011-02-13  2   1
                2011-03-28  3   1
                2011-04-16  2   1
                2011-06-09  1   1
                2011-06-27  3   1
                2011-07-17  2   1
                2011-09-05  1   1
                2011-09-16  2   1
                2011-10-29  3   1
                2011-11-06  1   0
Mr. Bean        2011-01-01  0   0
                2011-02-02  1   0
                        .
                        .
                        .
```

As you can see, the second level is a series of dates, which refer to the dates people have paid their rent. Some renters have missed payments on some months, or paid more than once on other months. I need to "homogenise" `paymentDate`, in other words, I want to have exactly 12 entries for the second level for all renters in the dataframe.

I believe the below should take care of it, but have no idea how to do it:

1. For each renter, if they have no `paymentDate` present for any given month, then insert that row with the `paymentDate` being the last day of that month, and `d=3` `p=1`. In the example above, this would entail adding a row for the month of May to `Balrud Big` like `2011-05-31  1   3`.
2. For each renter, I also need to remove cases where there are two or more `paymentDate` in the same month. Again if we look at `Balrud Big`, we see two entries for January. Wherever there are duplicates like this, I wish to keep only the *most recent* entry, which in this case is `2011-01-12  2   1`.

If the above was applied to the example shown, noting that `Balrud Big` has multiple cases of both missing entries and duplicates, I'd hope to end up with:

```
                            d   p
name            paymentDate

Rib Smoth       2011-01-01  0   0
                2011-02-01  0   0
                2011-03-01  0   0
                2011-04-01  0   0
                2011-05-01  0   0
                2011-06-01  0   0
                2011-07-01  0   0
                2011-08-01  0   0
                2011-09-01  0   0
                2011-10-01  0   0
                2011-11-01  0   0
                2011-12-01  0   0
Balrud Big      2011-01-12  2   1
                2011-02-13  2   1
                2011-03-28  3   1
                2011-04-16  2   1
                2011-05-31  3   1
                2011-06-27  3   1
                2011-07-17  2   1
                2011-08-31  3   1
                2011-09-16  2   1
                2011-10-29  3   1
                2011-11-06  1   0
                2011-12-31  3   1
Mr. Bean        2011-01-01  0   0
                2011-02-02  1   0
                        .
                        .
                        .
```

Finally, I could then reindex the second level with integers 1-12 (for the 12 months), safe in the knowledge every renter will have an *exact* 12 month history. Then, through the use of `DataFrame.pivot` or otherwise, transform the dataframe in order to end up with something like:

```
                d1  p1  d2  p2  d3  p3  d4  p4  d5  p5  d6  p6  d7  p7  d8  p8  d9  p9  d10  p10  d11  p11  d12  p12
name

Rib Smoth       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0
Balrud Big      2   1   2   1   3   1   2   1   3   1   3   1   2   1   3   1   2   1   3    1    1    0    3    0
Mr. Bean        0   0   1   0   ...(and so on)
```

It seems like quite a complex task but I imagine there may be some clever tricks using `DateTime` or `Pandas` extensive date/time functionality. I've been trying for a while and am still stumped.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** I have a solution, but it needs a bit of tidying up before I share.

Answer (score 0):

First, create the sample data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [
    np.array(['Rib Smoth']*12 + ['Balrud Big']*12 + ['Mr. Bean']*2),
    pd.to_datetime([
        '2011-01-01', '2011-02-01', '2011-03-01', '2011-04-01', '2011-05-01',
        '2011-06-01', '2011-07-01', '2011-08-01', '2011-09-01', '2011-10-01',
        '2011-11-01', '2011-12-01', '2011-01-02', '2011-01-12', '2011-02-13',
        '2011-03-28', '2011-04-16', '2011-06-09', '2011-06-27', '2011-07-17',
        '2011-09-05', '2011-09-16', '2011-10-29', '2011-11-06', '2011-01-01',
        '2011-02-02'])
]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*arrays)),
                                    names=['name', 'paymentDate'])
)
df['d'] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1]
df['p'] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
# print(df.head(3))
#                        d  p
# name      paymentDate      
# Rib Smoth 2011-01-01   0  0
#           2011-02-01   0  0
#           2011-03-01   0  0
```

Move `paymentDate` from index level to a column

```
df = df.reset_index(level='paymentDate')
# print(df.head(3))
#           paymentDate  d  p
# name                       
# Rib Smoth  2011-01-01  0  0
# Rib Smoth  2011-02-01  0  0
# Rib Smoth  2011-03-01  0  0
```

Create a series to be used when grouping by name and month

```
payment_month = df['paymentDate'].dt.to_period('M').rename('month')
# print(payment_month.head(3))
# name
# Rib Smoth    2011-01
# Rib Smoth    2011-02
# Rib Smoth    2011-03
# Name: month, dtype: period[M]
```

Group, keeping only the last payment in each month

```
df = df.groupby(['name', payment_month])[['paymentDate', 'd', 'p']].last()
# print(df.head(3))
#                    paymentDate  d  p
# name       month                    
# Balrud Big 2011-01  2011-01-12  2  1  # Note: last payment in 2011-01
#            2011-02  2011-02-13  2  1
#            2011-03  2011-03-28  3  1
```

Set the index to the last day of each month, for later use with months for which there is no payment

```
df.index = df.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[-1].to_timestamp('M'), 'month')
# print(df.head(3))
#                       paymentDate  d  p
# name       month                       
# Balrud Big 2011-01-31  2011-01-12  2  1
#            2011-02-28  2011-02-13  2  1
#            2011-03-31  2011-03-28  3  1
```

Fill in the dataframe with rows for missing months, by combining each name with all months

```
all_names = df.index.get_level_values('name').unique()
all_months = pd.date_range('2011-01-01', '2011-12-31', freq='M')
df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [all_names, all_months],
    names=['name', 'all_months']
))
# print(df.head())
#                       paymentDate    d    p
# name       all_months                      
# Balrud Big 2011-01-31  2011-01-12  2.0  1.0
#            2011-02-28  2011-02-13  2.0  1.0
#            2011-03-31  2011-03-28  3.0  1.0
#            2011-04-30  2011-04-16  2.0  1.0
#            2011-05-31         NaT  NaN  NaN # This row is new!
```

Complete the data with the desired values

```
no_payment = df['paymentDate'].isnull()
df.loc[no_payment, ['d', 'p']] = [3, 1]
df.loc[no_payment, ['paymentDate']] = df.index.get_level_values(-1)[no_payment]
# print(df.head())
#                       paymentDate    d    p
# name       all_months                      
# Balrud Big 2011-01-31  2011-01-12  2.0  1.0
#            2011-02-28  2011-02-13  2.0  1.0
#            2011-03-31  2011-03-28  3.0  1.0
#            2011-04-30  2011-04-16  2.0  1.0
#            2011-05-31  2011-05-31  3.0  1.0 # The column values are fixed!
```

Finally, replace the temporary index level by the column with correct values

```
df = df.set_index([df.index.get_level_values('name'), 'paymentDate'])
# print(df.head(3))
#                           d    p
# name       paymentDate          
# Balrud Big 2011-01-12   2.0  1.0
#            2011-02-13   2.0  1.0
#            2011-03-28   3.0  1.0
```

Restore the correct data types

```
df['d'] = df['d'].astype(int)
df['p'] = df['p'].astype(int)
# print(df.head(3))
#                         d  p
# name       paymentDate      
# Balrud Big 2011-01-12   2  1
#            2011-02-13   2  1
#            2011-03-28   3  1
```

Run some basic tests:

```
assert (df.loc[('Rib Smoth', slice(None))] == 0).all().all()
assert ('Balrud Big', '2011-01-02') not in df.index
assert ('Balrud Big', '2011-06-09') not in df.index
assert ('Balrud Big', '2011-09-05') not in df.index
assert (df.loc[('Balrud Big', '2011-01-12')] == [2, 1]).all()
assert (df.loc[('Balrud Big', '2011-12-31')] == [3, 1]).all()
```